# What do i need to substitute for word "site" in mod_wsgi daemon mode code

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, daemon

I am trying to wsgi in daemon mode. The code on their docs says to write this

```
WSGIDaemonProcess site-1 user=user-1 group=user-1 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup site-1
```

Now i want to know that what should i insert in place of `site1`

I mean if use domian name `www.example.com` then do i  need to insert that there

Also if i have multiple Django sites , can i use same `username` and `groupname` in the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument after to the `WSGIProcessGroup` directive is the process group name as used by the other mod_wsgi directives such as `WSGIDaemonProcess`; you can put any valid HTTPd configuration identifier in there.

You can assign any user and group desired to a daemon process, even users and groups that have already been used in others.

Comment: The only user you can't use is that for 'root'.

Comment: I could not understood what is `HTTPd configuration identifier`. I mean from where i can get that or i can use any name.

Comment: The word "any" is important; I recommend not skipping over it.

Comment: you mean i can use `Ignacio` this word there as long as its unique